# How to get the absolute XPath for an element using JavaFX, if the element doesn't have any attributes, like id, name, css etc

Tags: java, selenium, javafx

How to get the absolute XPath for an element using JavaFX, if the element doesn't have any attributes like id, name, css etc

```
html/body/tr/td[3]/div[2]/input
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's parents have any unique properties and it is a single child, you can find it's parent and direct it to its child.

html/body/tr/td[@class="classname"]/div[@id="idp"]/input

You can also find it's child if that has any unique identifiers and then direct it to its parent, so the xpath would look like

//*[@id="inputfieldchild"]/parent::*

Comment: Parent have multiple child's with same type, ex: all input tags.

Comment: Try using cssSelector